# android tomcat read servlet string text

Tags: java, android, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat7

i am very new to tomcat and android so i am trying to readservlet files but there some error .. need help. thanks! (what i trying to do is read the name from the tomcat database).

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    String name="";
    try {
      stmt = con.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM team7");
      while(rs.next()){
      name=rs.getString("");

      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {     }
    try {       rs.close();     }    catch (SQLException e) {     }

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println(name);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps would be :

1. Load the appropriate driver (Keep the driver class under WEB-INF/lib folder)
2. Create a `Connection` object.
3. Execute the `Statement`.
4. Iterate through the `ResultSet`.
5. Get the value of a particular row in a column.

Now , look at your code :

```
while(rs.next()){
   name=rs.getString(""); // you didn't provide the column name here
}
```

Ideally , if the name of the column is `name` , then your code should have been:

```
while(rs.next()){
   name=rs.getString("name"); // here the name of the column is name
}
```

You can use either one of the following methods :

[getString(columnIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)):

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> columnIndex - the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...

[getString(columnLabel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)):

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> columnLabel - the label for the column specified with the SQL AS clause. If the SQL AS clause was not specified, then the label is the name of the column

Go through the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) for more.